# Unknown number of spaces in a column of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008 with a `Latin1_General_CI_AS` collation.

Can someone help me understand how I can troubleshoot the below error?

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM table1 AS A 
INNER JOIN table2 AS B ON LTRIM(RTRIM('A.PPNO')) = LTRIM(RTRIM('B.PNO'))
WHERE A.OMPID = '1001'
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ' '.

Thanks

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  The first query has no indication of spaces being removed.  The second expression, well, it is not clear what it has to do with the first query.

Comment: This error isn't an error because of the data. It's to do with the syntax. It doesn't matter that A.PNO and B.PNO have spaces as values, it should still work. How are you running this query. If it's a query analyzer, are you mistakenly running other queries too?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Sorry i have edited the question. please help

Comment: you're passing through A.PPNO and B.PNO as strings, take the single quotes from around these to actually use these fields rather than static values.

Comment: Very odd, that syntax is correct. (But the query doesn't make much sense as string literals are compared as join condition...)

Comment: Have you copied this code from somewhere, ie from a mail or a webpage ??

Comment: @RichBenner: even after removed the quotes, error still exists.

Comment: @krish: no i have not copied from anywhere

Comment: if am selecting the 2 table separtely like select * from table1 or select * from table2. it is working. but when joining both causing the error..... very peculiar....... :)

Comment: @isle chow can you try one thing just remove A.* instead use * and check , i guess something to do with collation being used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT A.* FROM table1 AS A 
 INNER JOIN table2 AS B ON LTRIM(RTRIM(A.PPNO))= LTRIM(RTRIM(B.PNO))WHERE A.OMPID = '1001'
```

Comment: so it means there is an space, is it possible to remove all spaces for a specific column

Comment: its nothing related to space in column, its just that you were using column names in quotes which is not required.

Comment: "@RichBenner: even after removed the quotes, error still exists." So that was your problem then?

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that there's an issue on line 1. That looks like you may have a problem with a field in table A as you're using `SELECT *`.

Declare your fields properly and make sure you put them on separate lines, something like this;

```
SELECT 
A.Field1
,A.Field2
,A.Field3
,A.Field4 
FROM table1 AS A 
INNER JOIN table2 AS B 
    ON LTRIM(RTRIM(A.PPNO)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(B.PNO))
WHERE A.OMPID = '1001'
```

Then run it again. The error should tell you exactly which field you're having a problem with. It may be that the field name has something wrong with it. This is why we don't use `SELECT *`.

Comment: *syntax* errors are never raised based on *data*, since to get to the point of accessing data, the code has to have *compiled*, which it will not do if there's a syntax error.

Comment: Sure but there are no syntax issues with OP's code other than what was already suggested. I was trying to make sure that there's nothing odd with the field names that may cause an issue.

Comment: `Incorrect syntax near ' '.` sounds very much like a syntax issue to me.

Comment: Ok, point out the syntax error with the data we already have.